# IPython import from other cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to IPython.
I have a cell like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def hello():
        print("works")
```

And a second cell like so:

```
a = Foo()
a.hello()
```

Results in:

```
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

If I do

```
import Foo
```

in the second cell, I get an ImportError. How do I import from another cell in IPython?

Comment: Are you sure you have executed the first cell before executing the second? Otherwise it seems like an odd error. The error on the import makes sense, since you don't have a local Foo file, or library Foo installed.

Comment: You do not import from other cells. Think of a notebook like an interactive interpreter session mixed with a text-editor. You need to run your first cell.

Comment: Also you should have def hello(self):